# Extending in a package

Tags: java, package, extends

In the folder `.....\testPackage` I have a file `Test.java`:

```
package testPackage;
public class Test {}
```

and another file `OtherTest.java`:

```
package testPackage;
public class OtherTest extends Test {}
```

The second file won't compile, because it can't find the class `Test`. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
path\testPackage>javac Test.java

path\testPackage>java Test
Error: Could not find or load main class Test

path\testPackage>javac OtherTest.java
OtherTest.java:2: error: cannot find symbol
public class OtherTest extends Test {}
                               ^
  symbol: class Test
1 error
```

Weirdly enough, I don't get `Error: Could not find or load main class Test` when I run `Test` in TextPad (I know, how primitive right), but I do get the compilation error for `OtherTest`.

EDIT 2: Main problem already solved, but in case anyone else is wondering, the reason why `java Test` didn't work is because it's supposed to be `java testPackage.Test`, and in the parent folder of `testPackage`.

Comment: Have you compiled the first file before trying to compile the second?

Comment: Please provide the command you're using to compile your classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to packaging. You're running `javac` from the `testPackage` directory, so your classpath should actually be in the directory below. Here are 2 ways you can compile (assuming you've already compiled `Test.java`):

```
path\testPackage>javac -classpath ".." OtherTest.java
```

```
path>javac testPackage\OtherTest.java
```

For more details, here's a good article about classpaths: http://kevinboone.net/classpath.html